# could anyone pls tell me about web hosting and filezilla host username and password difference?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

Why we need host? (i knew about local host) then why many of them telling web hosting will come with domain name? I don't understand. Can anyone please clarify me?

Comment: Can you pls explain, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your qn is not that clear. But i will answer in bits

***Why we need host?***
To host the website online, so that public/others can use your website.

***(i knew about local host) then why many of them telling web hosting will come with domain name?***
When you use localhost,  it means you are hosting website in your local computer and no one else(not on your network) can access it over internet.
For others, to access your website, you need to use some web hosting providers like GoDaddy. 
Domain name is just a URL(address) to access your website. like you type www.stackoverflow.com to access StackOverflow

FileZilla Client: It is a software to transfer files over ftp protocol. Example, you will use this to transfer your website files over to web hosting provider(GoDaddy) account.